# regex replace not working in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to replace the `;` in data to `:` in HIVE
tried the following but not working

```
hive> select REGEXP_REPLACE('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel',';',':');
```

How to achieve this in HIVE. I am getting issues while transforming this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace characters in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090481/how-to-replace-characters-in-hive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `replace()`:

```
select replace('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel', ';', ':')
```

[`replace()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) is described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the semicolon. Please see below

```
hive> select REGEXP_REPLACE("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh\; Intel","\;",":");
OK
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh: Intel
Time taken: 0.082 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

U may try this

method 1: `REGEXP_REPLACE('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel','\;',':');`
method 2: `REGEXP_REPLACE('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel','\\;',':');`