# Hive: convert date to int

Tags: date, hive, int, data-conversion

Input looks like:

```
2017-07-03
```

Expected output looks like:

```
20170703
```

I tried the below code:

```
year(2017-07-03) * 10000 + month(2017-07-03) * 100 + day(2017-07-03))
```

Is there any built-in function that can do this conversion?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this? I would expect you to convert it to a long "Unix epoch"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` with `cast` to do this.

```
select cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-07-03','yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd') as int)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split on '-', then concatenate back again. Or replace "-" with "".

`regexp_replace("2017-07-03", "-", "")`

See [how to replace characters in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090481/how-to-replace-characters-in-hive)

Comment: cast(regexp_replace("2017-07-03", "-", "") as int)